# Why the Llama 2 language model keeps printing random garbage text when certain prompts are used?

Tags: llama-2

On the website https://llama2.ai/ you can test the llama 2 model.

But when I ask certain questions (or with some prompts) it sometimes prints random nonsense text. I tried reducing the "temperature" parameter, but nothing changed.

Try asking "give me names related to fire for fictional characters" to llama 2 using that website to see what happens.

Is this caused because of the model leaking its training data?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Both llama2-70b and codellama-34b gave me a list of names related to fire.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue (default settings): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofECK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character salad of the sort [posted by galacticninja in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofECK.png) is unrelated to your prompt, the temperature, or any training data.

LLMs don't work with words, or with individual letters.  They work with "tokens": numbers representing words or word fragments.  The first step in interacting with an LLM is turning the prompt into a series of tokens; the final step is turning the output tokens into text.

Character salad happens when something goes wrong during the last step and an incorrect token-to-text mapping gets used.  This could be for any of a number of reasons, but is usually due to hardware malfunctions or bugs in the code running the model.

(If an incorrect mapping is used during the first step, the output is still coherent, it's just unrelated to the prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

https://llama2.ai/ with your prompt

> give me names related to fire for fictional characters

works fine on my side:

[image]

I kept all the default settings:

[image]